# What is the cause of this strange security behavior?

Tags: ssh

The following commands (server names obfuscated), in sequence, works correctly:

```
ssh xxx.sjc
sudo -u appName id
```

However, when I try to chain them together, things break:

```
ssh xxx.sjc 'sudo -u appName id'
Sorry, user merlin2011 is not allowed to execute '/bin/id' as appName on xxx.sjc.
```

What differences between the two modes of `ssh` might cause this, and what can I do to investigate?

In terms of OS, I'm running OSX on the client and a custom Linux distro on the server (deployed by someone else at my company).

```
uname -r
3.10.0-1127.18.2.el7.x86_64
```

Comment: Please try replacing the `sudo -u appName id` in both cases with `type sudo`. I'd be interested to know if they report the same application path

Comment: Also, please [edit] and tell us your operating system as well as any special setting you may have (especially for the users `merlin2011` and `appName`) in your sudoers files.

Comment: A TTY Requirement? Tried `ssh -t ...`?

Comment: @roaima That is a fascinating suggestion. It appears that they *do not*!

Comment: @muru That one I did try. It had the benefit of hiding my password, but no other difference.

Comment: @roaima I think you answered the question. 
By using the full path to the same version as sudo as that used in the interactive mode, I managed to make the non-interactive version work!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Based on [my comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/609816/what-is-the-cause-of-this-strange-security-behavior?noredirect=1#comment1138260_609816) suggestion

> Please try replacing the `sudo -u appName id` in both cases with `type sudo`. I'd be interested to know if they report the same application path

and [your response](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/609816/what-is-the-cause-of-this-strange-security-behavior?noredirect=1#comment1138274_609816),

> It appears that they do not!

it seems that there are two installations of `sudo` using two different `sudoers` configurations. The version of `sudo` that you are expected to use is probably in a non-standard location such as `/usr/local/bin/sudo` or `/opt/bin/sudo` that is added to a user's `PATH` in a login script, which means that this command usually overrides the otherwise unused `/usr/bin/sudo`

A work-around is to provide the full path to the "working" `sudo` command on your `ssh` command line. As an aside, if `sudo` prompts for a password, or your target application expects input from the user, make sure you're using `ssh -t` rather than just `ssh`.